# how to prevent seaborn from smoothing the histogram when plotting a density plot using seaborn.distplot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn, density-plot

Here is the problem I'm facing for a while now. I'm trying to plot a density plot (i.e. a smoothed approximation of a histogram plot) using `seaborn.distplot()` and I obtain the following figure:

[image: density plot]

The problem with the above plot is that the contour on the leftmost side extends well beyond -1.0 and I do not want that since the similarity score cannot be less than -1.0 (i.e. it should only lie in the closed interval `[-1.0, 1.0]`). I have checked my input array (given below) for values less than -1.0 and there's no such value which is less than -1.0. So, it seems that `seaborn.distplot()` smoothens the distribution which makes it to extend well beyond -1.0. How can I stop this from happening? I have tried setting `xlim` on the x-axis but that doesn't leave any room on the left hand side of  the plot (like we have a single column on the rightmost side after +1.0).

For an illustration, here is a sample input array and code that I'm using for plotting:

```
arr = np.array([-0.35416853, -0.28675528, -0.54088942,  0.18797232,  0.01707244,
       -0.48090636, -0.44454523, -0.03228283, -0.70861904,  0.02323842,
       -0.54905541, -0.5421915 ,  0.27547336, -0.92913273, -0.55379011,
       -0.23521681, -0.1079175 , -0.24065031, -0.33773661, -0.06147251,
       -0.74171701, -0.74315048,  0.06634989, -0.49222919,  0.48899574,
        0.13499221,  0.53120786, -0.1688146 ,  0.47125832,  0.36517109,
        0.33110315,  0.34495851,  0.18393   ,  0.67211736,  0.11608325,
       -0.92913273, -0.71209124,  0.01828323,  0.30894561, -0.06463642,
        0.45423401, -0.7993457 ,  0.50007295,  0.17983021, -0.66105515,
       -0.92783269, -0.49277017, -0.19487059,  0.07502782,  0.00700057,
        0.29958942, -0.04223299,  0.04105657, -0.12604522,  0.30506049,
       -0.15600141, -0.17434894,  0.01152945, -0.11583157,  0.07010729,
       -0.92913273, -0.02566766,  0.48114331, -0.13252103, -0.42600686,
        0.54836633,  0.37945642, -0.34006735, -0.29560479,  0.4930249 ,
        0.02693856,  0.57255816,  0.31185216,  0.19780182,  0.11909931,
       -0.02853919, -0.25082142, -0.08635957, -0.28266912, -0.80937364,
       -0.92913273, -0.0172393 , -0.18993503, -0.69080226, -0.66901143,
        0.0470842 , -0.45307088,  0.05043218, -0.20894534, -0.22218531,
        0.5189177 , -0.92913273,  0.31509469, -0.15935917, -0.92913273,
       -0.41652189,  0.20265061,  0.016976  ,  0.0680205 ,  0.33159134,
       -0.3138477 ,  0.10086817,  0.37074665, -0.06916329, -0.19177307,
        0.22842641, -0.15087903,  0.34376167,  0.24173604, -0.38040409,
       -0.20031291,  0.17990511,  0.40231535, -0.27195479, -0.15867829,
        0.2389052 ,  0.08337308, -0.07327617, -0.77566734, -0.12074809,
        0.19539527,  0.03727124, -0.13330546,  0.13602168,  0.36673224,
       -0.3434154 ,  0.19251896,  0.27692974,  0.4757158 ,  0.24333386,
        0.29905657,  0.57319178,  0.46753947, -0.04079389,  0.5571865 ,
        0.3453707 ,  0.55110949,  0.19614831,  0.61707333,  0.3680048 ,
        0.48193126,  0.67330892,  0.53603774,  0.54464057,  0.35016492,
        0.36970268,  0.150395  ,  0.4697073 ,  0.3383952 ,  0.4037419 ,
       -0.01055328,  0.26734498,  0.2647191 ,  0.30056532,  0.46706568,
        0.41460328,  0.42295413,  0.44188908,  0.29304088, -0.18437651,
       -0.33404869,  0.31744862,  0.16578238, -0.2903621 , -0.36128032,
       -0.65571561,  0.39868119, -0.31359498,  0.45377302,  0.23929229,
        0.19958669,  0.51978988, -0.01249307, -0.16404641,  0.27193916,
       -0.11159726, -0.10719093,  0.05472177, -0.64784851,  0.25594644,
       -0.26109644, -0.28908332,  0.06264426,  0.05689891,  0.26437733,
       -0.29424862,  0.26441642,  0.34868516,  0.00497344, -0.46811445,
       -0.35795662, -0.04599685,  0.08701907, -0.32572399,  0.17639076,
        0.35640737, -0.08174591, -0.13910904,  0.35387245,  0.00857055,
       -0.24789401,  0.24033791, -0.08525459,  0.19189512,  0.27148848,
       -0.38631975, -0.08820518,  0.12658585,  0.23404602,  0.06062359,
        0.13340842, -0.11942433, -0.15974527, -0.0236961 ,  0.01533685,
       -0.92641117,  0.01533685, -0.00582898,  0.08251113, -0.18537655,
       -0.92641117, -0.63036561, -0.02408175, -0.10033362, -0.08820518,
        0.01533685, -0.1475904 , -0.06573955, -0.10033362, -0.08820518,
       -0.08820518,  0.04798457,  0.29057868,  0.08310757,  0.25168328,
        0.03989156,  0.1895359 , -0.44324531, -0.16724842,  0.06172038,
        0.05685105,  0.3381661 , -0.46472578, -0.13137012,  0.10249921,
        0.26703853,  0.14798872,  0.09729466, -0.09559039,  0.38893042,
        0.6081168 , -0.32574556, -0.11493626,  0.30370567, -0.13203101,
        0.12251789,  0.29993512, -0.80796771, -0.14717629,  0.37894796,
        0.30086822,  0.26228619, -0.01403568, -0.46596314, -0.11860131,
       -0.52649509,  0.41834337,  0.25892792,  0.40497516, -0.0287142 ,
       -0.14994142,  0.41714702,  0.40928704,  0.0595943 ,  0.5190621 ,
        0.53760238,  0.25452441, -0.08397463,  0.22131469, -0.46173602,
        0.48456617,  0.44220971,  0.16059022,  0.43723123,  0.04680989,
       -0.00131657, -0.09681387, -0.48600167, -0.44205123,  0.13787778,
       -0.02900436,  0.07049823,  0.02565475, -0.20544388,  0.0297263 ,
        0.09162641, -0.17354248, -0.41518963,  0.12393266, -0.41754063,
       -0.19018751,  0.02251257, -0.27799953,  0.21135703,  0.09597453,
        0.56175636,  0.34126265,  0.17056669,  0.13149045, -0.30472518,
       -0.07366951,  0.42843431, -0.22890901,  0.05518269, -0.01007775,
       -0.48123104, -0.44906545,  0.09229373, -0.85684002,  0.23411821,
        0.02637603,  0.02477345,  0.21678001, -0.14454807,  0.32430986,
       -0.12988135,  0.07014938,  0.17991853, -0.02405694, -0.83110188,
       -0.11192697,  0.02312546, -0.10770876,  0.13470276,  0.10568144,
       -0.20336714, -0.15739212,  0.21271663,  0.05357167,  0.3281988 ,
        0.17442453,  0.11561338, -0.68398479, -0.03704769,  0.28698584,
        0.17608064,  0.30424182,  0.51034264, -0.09452418,  0.38242868,
       -0.60014916,  0.21856565, -0.04819684,  0.2653766 ,  0.02992649,
        0.18941891, -0.04752845,  0.02295903, -0.29201727,  0.07913569,
       -0.12563984,  0.21124929, -0.18801383, -0.24118712, -0.29686842,
        0.27609838, -0.23855832,  0.31970457,  0.41328374,  0.19630546,
        0.34077982, -0.3704136 ,  0.17032295,  0.20643397,  0.34154881,
        0.1504677 ,  0.37392242,  0.25842101, -0.50553798,  0.35387764,
        0.41873554,  0.27067669,  0.31011181, -0.51092977, -0.10282291,
       -0.4126883 , -0.52383119, -0.82821877, -0.4585979 ,  0.2531493 ,
        0.34361492,  0.38418371, -0.22988404,  0.285816  , -0.40203361,
        0.38114577,  0.15781548,  0.27335741,  0.36371593,  0.36515941])
```

---

```
In [57]: ax = sns.distplot(arr, hist=False, kde_kws={"shade": True}, norm_hist=True, label="density plot")

In [58]: plt.plot(np.array([-0.208, -0.208]), np.array([0, 2]), color='grey', linestyle='--')
In [59]: plt.plot(np.array([0.317, 0.317]), np.array([0, 2]), color='grey', linestyle='--')    
In [60]: ax.set_xlabel(r"similarity")
In [61]: ax.set_ylabel(r"density")
In [62]: plt.show()
```

---

So, I'd like to not have this smoothing on the left side of the plot and leave one column spacing as in the rightmost side of the plot. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: The distplot shows a KDE (kernel density estimate), which is a probability density function. If you know of a mathematical sound way of defining such pdf in a way that  does not go from -infinity to +inifinity, you can implement that, but you will need to plot it yourself as seaborn uses the commonly known definition of a kde and cannot be customized in this respect.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks! are there any other alternatives to `distplot()` which does not do this smoothing? Actually the area under the curve from `[-1.0, 1.0]` itself integrates to 1. So, it's sort of misleading that the plot extends well beyond `-1.0`

Comment: No the area under the curve from -infinity to +infinity integrates to 1, per definition of a probability density function.

Comment: It's still confounding me. For e.g. this post: [the-total-area-underneath-a-probability-density-function-is-1-relative-to](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/133370/122556) explains the concept very well. I still fail to see how do we get a +ve prob. mass while integrating in the interval `[-inf, -1.0)`. Could you please clarify?

Comment: KDE needs to use a finite kernel, so a kernel that has a certain width ("bandwidth"). The convolution with the kernel will eventually lead to parts of the distribution outside the range of your data. I have no idea how mathematically sound the convolution with an adaptive kernel like the one in the answer below is.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to get desired result is to use custom window and kernel. Both kernel and
window should depends  on the position of the window's center relative to interval's edge points  `a` and `b`.

Searborn uses `stats.gaussian_kde` or kde estimatior from statsmodels,  if the latter is installed.
As far as I know about `gaussian_kde`, it doesn't allow such tweaking. So, we need to implement custom kde estimator.

Look at the following code snippet, it works and can be considered as a starting point for further improvement.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

class kde:

    def __init__(self, a, b, kernel=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def h(self, x):
        """ h(x) window size depends on position of the center of the window relative to (a, b).

        _ r    ___________   <-- rthumb = r = height of the graph
        |     /           \ 
        |    /             \
        |---|--|----------|-|----- 
            a  a+r      b-r b

        """

        if x > (self.a + self.rthumb) and x < (self.b - self.rthumb):
            return self.rthumb
        elif x >= self.a and (x < self.a + self.rthumb):
            return x - self.a + np.finfo(float).eps
        elif (x <= self.b) and (x > self.b - self.rthumb):
            return self.b - x + np.finfo(float).eps
        else:
            return + np.finfo(float).eps

    def kernel(self, x):
        return np.exp(-0.5 * x ** 2) / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi);

    def window(self, x):
        """ x - scalar value """
        def w(y):
            res = self.kernel((x - y) / self.h(x))  # gaussian kernel
            res[(y > self.b) | (y < self.a)] = 0.0  # window is zero outside [a, b]~
            return res
        return w

    def fit(self, data):
        # Rule of thumb
        self.rthumb = 1.06 * np.std(data) * np.power(len(data), -1/5) 
        def _pdf(x):
            ww = self.window(x)
            return ww(data).sum() / len(data)
        val = quad(_pdf, self.a, self.b)[0]
        def pdf_norm(f):
            def pn(x):
                return f(x) / val
            return pn
        self.pdf = np.vectorize(pdf_norm(_pdf))
        return self
```

If we apply it to your data:

```
k = kde(-1, 1)
from pylab import plt
x = np.linspace(-1,  1, 100)
plt.plot(x, k.fit(arr).pdf(x))
```

we get:

[image]

If the sliding window is close to edges of the interval, it is truncated:

```
plt.plot(x, k.window(0.9)(x), 'r.', x, k.window(0)(x), x, k.window(-.9)(x),'r.')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note, this custom class produces normalized pdf estimations, e.g. AUC(kde.pdf) = 1.

EDITED:

I added small value (float's epsilon 1)  to  h(x) value, and now everything
works without warnings.

In general, trying to obtain kernel density estimation is made under assumption that the theoretical pdf is a smooth function. In your case, 
you can truncate the pdf obtained using gaussian_kde from scipy,
and finally add some constant to truncated estimation to meet AUC = 1. 
Some distributions have discontinuities of the first kind, e.g. pdf of the uniform distribution.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your suggestion and get the following warnings (no plots):  `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide`,   `res = self.kernel((x - y) / self.h(x))  # gaussian kernel` and `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars`, `return f(x) / val`

Comment: This is because window width becomes zero at points `a` and `b`, h(a) = h(b) =0; I look at this later...